# Term rewrite system is non-confluent, but cannot find different normal forms of term

Tags: normal-forms, term-rewriting

I wrote a simple TRS that I believe is non-confluent, but I'm not able to find a term with two normal forms for it.

The TRS is defined on the signature $\mathcal F=\{f,\ l,\ s,\ o\}$ and the rewrite rules $\mathcal R$ are defined as follows:

- $l\to s(o)$
- $t(x,\ l)\to s(x)$
- $t(l,\ x)\to s(x)$.

This TRS is clearly finite and terminating.

For the first two rules, we have a critical pair $(t(x,\ s(o)),\ s(x))$ which is not joinable. Therefore, the TRS is not confluent.

It seems that for such a simple example I should be able to find a term with two normal forms. What am I missing?

Comment: Stating that the critical pair is not joinable means that the original term $t(x,l)$ can reduce along two non-joinable paths. Since the system is normalizing, both paths must end in a normal form. As it were, the two terms you have here are both normal forms for $t(x,l)$. I don't get what you're missing...

Comment: Your rewrite system is not confluent (as you have shown) but perhaps what you want to show is that it is not confluent *when restricted to ground terms* (i.e., terms with no variables). This property, called ground-confluence, is different from confluence (actually, it is a bit weaker). Can you confirm this is indeed your question?

Comment: I indeed had the two terms that are different normal forms of a given term in front of me. I didn't have a good enough understanding of what the meaning of a critical pair is. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t(o,l)$ has two normal forms: $t(o,l)\to s(o)$ and $t(o,l)\to t(o,s(o))$.